# Yii 2.0 static link to a controller

Tags: php, yii2

I'm very new to Yii 2.03 (and frameworks in general). I'm facing some problem now.

On the main page I have a menu on which I want to place (in the view) the link to the controller, but I don't know how, I'm getting " PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'CHtml' not found" or " PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'Html' not found"

`http://localhost/web/index.php` is the main page with the menu.
`http://localhost/web/index.php?r=autori/index` is the page with the generated CRUD, which works perfectly.
In the view I have `<li><a href="#">Autori</a></li>` and I want to replace the '#' with a valid link, I don't care for SEO now. How can I edit the view to use the specific controller?

Thanks!

Comment: try this `<?php echo CHtml::link("Autori" , array("/autori/index ") , array('class' => 'link_class')); ?>`

Comment: CHtml looks like you are using Yii 1.x, not Yii 2.x btw !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are indeed using Yii2, then try using:

```
<li><a href="<?=Url::to(["autori/index"])?>">Autori</a></li>
```

You'll need to include this in the beginning of your view file, so it uses the correct namespace for the Url helper class:

```
<?php use yii\helpers\Url ?>
```

But pay attention to the framework version, as Sliq noted, CHtml is a Yii1 class.